# I couldn't use my credit card to book tickets with Iranian Mahan Air

Tags: air-travel, iran

I've tried to book a single ticket from Shiraz to Tehran with Mahan Air. But they never accepted my (Belgian) credit card.

I wonder if there are any alternative ways I can book it.

Comment: Seems the airline website has a credit card payment option only. You can visit the airline's office or book via some agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, for Iranian airlines (Mahan, Iran Air,..) you should always book via an agency as they still don't have international payment systems (mainly due to sanctions); as an alternative you can look for an agency that works with them in the city/country of your residence and give them a call!

Generally these sale points work like this: receive your request, look for a ticket in your preferred date, inform you of the exact available date and the corresponding price, along with an IBAN and a deadline to pay.

In the links below you can find list of their official sale offices:

[Mahan Air](http://www.mahan.aero/en/contact/sales-offices)

[Iran Air](http://www.iranair.com/portal/Home/?10665/International-Sales-Office)

If you can't find an official sale office nearby, there might be some other local agencies that sell their tickets. You can find out about them by contacting them.